# Remove user/application access from firebase

Tags: firebase

I have a consultant working an app. The app uses Firebase db to do crud operations. While the project is heading to completion I want to ensure that the consultant does not have access to the firebase db. And he cannot access it via the application either.
Based on some research, I can remove the consultant access from Firebase but I am not clear on how to restrict him from running any operations using the code/google-services.json file.

Thanks